# Firebase database: Permission denied for reading?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to read from my firebase database and put it with adapter to Recyclerview, but every time I get this:

```
08-20 18:26:53.754 3430-3653/blabla.com.notescloud W/SyncTree: Listen at / failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
08-20 18:26:53.764 3430-3430/blabla.com.notescloud W/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Permission denied
     at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError.toException(Unknown Source)
     at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCancelled(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:175)
     at com.firebase.ui.database.ObservableSnapshotArray.notifyListenersOnCancelled(ObservableSnapshotArray.java:135)
     at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseArray.onCancelled(FirebaseArray.java:129)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdpw.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvg.zzbur(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvo.run(Unknown Source)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

My rules are ok(for the record, writing to the database work very good):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My database:

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWVJf.png)
This is the recycler setup in my main activity:

```
rv = findViewById(R.id.rv_notes); //RecyclerView
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); // Getting a reference of the database

mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Note, NoteHolderView>(
        Note.class,
        android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
        NoteHolderView.class,
        ref) {
    @Override
    public void populateViewHolder(NoteHolderView holder, Note note, int position) {
        holder.setmTitleField(note.getmTitle());
        holder.setmTimeField(note.getTimeFormatted(getApplicationContext()));
    }
};
rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Hope you will be able to help me solve this problam.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to read at the top of your database, and since you didnt specified rules for that, it is automatically denied.
Try this

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                      .getReference()
                      .child("users")
                      .child(FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the collection by putting  / prefix to Collection so that means it get called.Like mine I have tried this and it worked fine Hope this helps.

```
 db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    dbref=db.getReference("/Course_list");
```

in this code I have added the "/" prefix to collection.